# UTType Supertypes not available when running on device

Tags: ios, swift, file

Accessing `UTType.supertype` for a JPG file when ran on iOS simulator return this:

```
[<_UTCoreType 0x1121549b0> public.item (not dynamic, declared), <_UTCoreType 0x112154a30> public.data (not dynamic, declared), <_UTCoreType 0x112155090> public.image (not dynamic, declared), <_UTCoreType 0x1121549d0> public.content (not dynamic, declared)]
```

But when ran on h/w device returns this:

```
[<_UTCoreType 0x204f85b80> public.jpeg (not dynamic, declared)]
```

Anyone know how to get all the super types on h/w device?

Comment: solved problem?

Comment: Not working for me as well. Have you solved the problem?